# Form object from Array of objects based of value

Tags: javascript

Need to search objects array and form an object based on the value 'X' and 'AND'/OR. Tried with below code but couldnt proceed

**Input :**

```
 let objArr = [ {"L1":"NA","L2":"X","L1L2":"NA","L3":"NA"},{"L1":"X","L2":"NA","L1L2":"AND","L3":"NA"} ]
```

**Output:**

```
Obj = {"L1":"X","L2":"X","L1L2":"AND","L3":"NA"}
```

**Code:**

```
 Object.keys(objArr ).forEach((key) => {
      if (!(temp[key] == "X" || temp[key] == "AND" || temp[key] == "OR")) {
        temp[key] = objArr [key]
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the keys and map the entries after a check and create a new object.

```js
let array = [
      { L1: "NA", L2: "X",  L1L2: "NA",  L3: "NA" },
      { L1: "X",  L2: "NA", L1L2: "AND", L3: "NA" }
    ],
    prime = ['X', 'AND', 'OR'],
    result = array.reduce((a, b) => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .keys(a)
        .map(k => [k, prime.includes(b[k]) ? b[k] : a[k]])
    ));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using `reduce` method and one `for...of` loop inside it on `Object.entries`.

```js
let objArr = [ {"L1":"NA","L2":"X","L1L2":"NA","L3":"NA"},{"L1":"X","L2":"NA","L1L2":"AND","L3":"NA"} ]

let result = objArr.reduce((r, e) => {
  for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(e)) {
    r[k] = (!r[k] || r[k] == 'NA') ? v : r[k]
  }

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```